# VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) No compatible source was found for this media

Tags: reactjs, video.js

With this code (React-Electron-Typescript ) :

```
import VideoJS from './videojs/VideoJS'
import "videojs-youtube"

function App_C(props) {
  const [url, setUrl] = React.useState("")

  const playerRef = React.useRef(null)

  console.log("App_C-url-updated: ", url)

  const changeVideoSource = (player) => {
    playerRef.current = player;
    //setUrl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voFRslp8d60')
    player.changeSource(url)
  }

  const videoJsOptions = { // lookup the options in the docs for more options
    autoplay: true,
    controls: true,
    responsive: true,
    fluid: true,
    sources: [
      {
      src: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voFRslp8d60',
      type: 'video/youtube'
      },
      {
        src: '/path/to/video.mp4',
        type: 'video/mp4'
      }
    ]
  }


  const handlePlayerReady = (player) => {
    playerRef.current = player;

    // you can handle player events here
    player.on('waiting', () => {
      console.log('player is waiting');
    });

    player.on('dispose', () => {
      console.log('player will dispose');
    });
  };


    return (
      <div id="outer-container" className='outer-container'>
       <h1>App_C</h1>

       <VideoJS options={videoJsOptions} onReady={handlePlayerReady} />

      </div>
    );
}

export default App_C;
```

[image]

But I get this error message:

[image]

if I want to set the  video`source` to the `url` (a string)  :

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voFRslp8d60")
  }, [])

  console.log("App_C-url-updated: ", url)

  const changeVideoSource = (player) => {
    playerRef.current = player;
    //setUrl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voFRslp8d60')
    player.changeSource(url)
  }

  const videoJsOptions = { // lookup the options in the docs for more options
    autoplay: true,
    controls: true,
    responsive: true,
    fluid: true,
    sources: [
      {
        src: changeVideoSource,
        type: 'video/youtube'
      },
      {
        src: '/path/to/video.mp4',
        type: 'video/mp4'
      }
    ]
  }
```

Or:

```
  const videoJsOptions = { // lookup the options in the docs for more options
    autoplay: true,
    controls: true,
    responsive: true,
    fluid: true,
    sources: [
      {
        src: url,
        type: 'video/youtube'
      },
      {
        src: '/path/to/video.mp4',
        type: 'video/mp4'
      }
    ]
  }
```

Other info:

```
"react": "^17.0.2"
"video.js": "^7.17.0"
"videojs-youtube": "^2.6.1"
"electron": "^16.0.7"
node: v16.13.0
O.S. : Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop
```

I'm having some problem in importing modules in `codesandbox`,

```
ModuleNotFoundError
Could not find module in path: 'mux.js/lib/tools/parse-sidx' 
relative to '/node_modules/video.js/dist/video.es.js'
```

but I've put all the code in this `codesandbox repo`:
https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-yalow-y6g73

How to make it work?

Comment: Did you get any answer for this question?

Comment: Hi @RafiHaidari Unfortunately no answers ...

Comment: This was answered [on GitHub](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/7636).